# Recursion en Linked List

Tags: javascript, lista, recursión

Hola he estado practicando linked list y quería implementar recursión en el mismo, si bien en algunos casos lo pude implementar de manera eficiente en otros casos he fallado miserablemente en hacerlo.
Quisiera saber un metodo de hacer la recursión para no tener que hacer uso de los "while" para recorrer la Linked List, he usado recursión para recorrer arrays pero cuando lo quise hacer similar en este caso  se "rompe".

No tengo mucha experiencia implementado recursión y quería aplicarla en este método para obtener mas experiencia en el mismo, pero por lo menos me ayudo a entender mas las Linked List al tener que armarla una y otra vez.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

```js
class Node {
    // Accept arguments (the second one could be optional)
    constructor(data, next) {
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = next;
    }
    lastNode() { // new method that uses recursion
        return this.next?.lastNode() || this;
    }
}
class ListRecurse {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    add(data) {
        let newNode = new Node(data); // No second argument. It has a default value
        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            // The lastNode implementation uses recursion:
            this.head.lastNode().next = newNode;
        }
        this.size ++;
        return this; // to allow chaining
    }
    insertAdd(data, index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > this.size) {
            return null;
        }
        let newNode = new Node(data);
        let current = this.head;
        let prev;
        if (index === 0) {
            newNode.next = current;
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            this.head.lastNode().next = current;
            prev.next = newNode;
        }
        this.size++;
        return this;
    }
    Print() {
        if (!this.size) {
            return null;
        }
        let current = this.head;
        let resultado = "";
        while(current) {
            resultado += current.data += "=>";
            current = current.next;
        }
        resultado += "X";
        return resultado;
        }
    DeletexData(data) {
           let current = this.head;
           let prev = null;
           if (this.head === null) {
               return null;
           }
           else if (current.data === data) {
               if(!prev) {
                   this.head = this.head.next;
               }
               else
               prev.next = current.next
           }
           return this.SearchDelete(data)
           }
    SearchDelete (data) {
            let current = this.head;
            let prev = null;
            while(current != null) {
                if (current.data === data) {
                    if (!current.next) prev.next = null
                else prev.next = current.next
                    this.size--;
                    return data;
                    }
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        return null;
        }
    DeleteLastNode() {
        let current = this.head;
        if (current === null) {
            return 1
        }
        else if (current.next === null) {
            this.head = null;
        }
        else return this.LastNode()
        };
    LastNode() {
        let current = this.head;
        while (current.next.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = null;
        this.size--;
    }
    Search(data) {
        let current = this.head;
        if (current === null) {
            return null;
        }
        else 
        return this.RainbowSix(data)
    }
    RainbowSix(data) {
        let current = this.head; 
        while (current) {
            if (current.data === data) {
                return current;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
    Size(){
        return this.size
    }
}
let list = new ListRecurse();
list.add(1).add(2).add(3).add(44).add(66);
list.insertAdd(33,0)
list.DeleteLastNode()
console.log(list.Search(3))
console.log(list.Size())
console.log(list.Print())
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos podes crear una función auxiliar dentro de la propia función para ir recorriendo recursivamente la lista, te dejo un ejemplo de la búsqueda.

```
Search(data){
    let current = this.head;
    if (current === null) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const findData = (node)=>{
        if(node == null || node.data === data){
            return node
        }
        return findData(node.next)
    }
    return findData(current)
}
```